# model.predict() returning random float instead of 3 probabilities

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

My model takes as input like 'USD' and predicts the category of it, in this case 1 since I defined currency to be 1. In total there's three categories to predict: `0=book name`, `1=currency`, or `2=security` number. My training, validation, and test sets look like this, where the value is mapped to it's label.

```
         Value          Label
0   CAT_USD_CORP          0
1   USD                   1
2   US348595EV89          2
3   ATTR_IRT_LDN_ISD_ISD  0
4   CAD                   1
              ...
```

and I trained and tested the model with this code which works perfectly fine and gives me good accuracy:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dropout(.1),
  layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_ds,
          validation_data=val_ds,
          epochs=12)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_ds)
print("Accuracy", accuracy)
```

but when I try to predict a value I input it always gives me an array of a random float instead of the probability of the 3 categories it falls under for example:

`model.predict(np.array(['USD']))` returns `array([[1195770.]], dtype=float32)`
and

`model.predict(np.array(['US568A45EV89']))` returns `array([[1938599.4]], dtype=float32)`,

when they're supposed to return an array of 3 probabilities.

Comment: I might not understand your question correctly, but: As you specified `layers.Dense(1)` the final layer has one unit, i.e. that's the final dim. If you want a dimension of 3, i.e. get a vector, you have to increase the number of units in the last layer.

Comment: Binary classification means two classes, not the same as three classes, so your whole model setup is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 3 classes then the top layer of your model should have 3 nodes as in

```
layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
```

In model.compile you have

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

If you have 3 classes this is NOT binary. If your labels are one hot encoded use

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
```

if integer encode use

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
```

Then when you do predictions each prediction will be a list of 3 values

Answer (score 1):

Output dense layer should be 3 based on your total class.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dropout(.1),
  layers.Dense(3)
])
```